# Capture Min() And Max() Of Numbers Input

Tags: c#, performance

I have two text boxes where a user inputs a start and a end, that is how it is supposed to work at least.  Rather than throwing an error if end < start, I was thinking I could use the built in functions Min() & Max() to capture which value is actually which.

Is this the most efficient way of capturing the Min() & Max() value of text box input?

```
int start = Math.Min(Convert.ToInt32(txtStart.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtEnd.Text));
int end = Math.Max(Convert.ToInt32(txtStart.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtEnd.Text));
```

Comment: This is a very simple question, I am not sure that this would make a good question that would get many reviews that would help other users learn about C# or Performance.

Answer (score 2):

not going to be much better than what you have
only parse once and only compare once

```
int min = Convert.ToInt32(txtStart.Text);
int max = Convert.ToInt32(txtEnd.Text);
if(max < min)
{
   int temp = min;
   min = max;
   max = temp;
}
```